# C++ - Image Conversion

Tags: c++, image-processing

I am new to C++ and would like to know how to read in a .jpg image and then convert it to binary (black and white/bi-level/two-level)?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're new to C++, why are you trying to jump in at the deep end? Find a good beginners guide (they're usually good for beginners) and start with the basics.

Comment: I have experience in Java - I didn't say that I am a programming beginner, just C++. Thank you for the advice, all the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your better choice is probably [boost Gil](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html).
Boost libraries are not especially for beginner, but they are often well designed.

```
#include <boost/gil/image.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/typedefs.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io.hpp>

int main() {
  using namespace boost::gil;

  rgb8_image_t img;
  jpeg_read_image("test.jpg",img);

  gray8s_view_t view(img.dimensions());
  color_converted_view<gray8_pixel_t>(const_view(img), view);

  jpeg_write_view("grey.jpg", view);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) to read the image. It supports a lot of different formats.

To convert it to pure black and white, you then go through the whole image data and compute the intensity or light contribution of each pixel and if it falls below a certain threshold you'll output a black pixel otherwise a white pixel.

You could do it as simply as check the RGB-values of each pixel against a threshold of RGB(0.5, 0.5, 0.5). But you might get better results if you convert the image to [HSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and use the intensity value for each pixel, but that's more work.

Answer (score 0):

There is the option for [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/), which as been used on many projects. For additional reading on how to write a grayscale image, take a look at [this chapter from their website.](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter15.html)